# Is it possible to inject a content-script into a web page without a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, web

I know this is a shady question and I promise I don't have malicious intent - I am hoping to get an answer that provides security against using it to conduct fishing attacks on a vendor's domain.

Currently I am accustomed to writing private Chrome extensions to "fix up" the limitations of websites I frequent (such as adding folders/category tags in my YouTube subscriptions) by injecting a JavaScript content script on certain domains.

These enhancements are not available on mobile devices because you cannot use browser extensions. I would love to add my enhancements to my mobile browser but don't know how to inject my content script.

I would imagine it's not possible to add JavaScript into a URL, so I can't add my content scripts to my bookmarks. e.g.

```
https://google.com;javascript:alert(42)
```

I was thinking I could set up an http proxy that lives on it own domain, such as:

```
https://youtube.enhanced.app
```

and this proxy intercepts the index.html and injects the enhanced content script (making it an installable web app and fixing up UI issues). But of course then I have to pay the bandwidth of the vendor page while also not benefiting from their caching and optimization.

Are there any alternative ways for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a *custom browser* running on mobile. Tampermonkey is probably the most common tool for running client-written JS on others' pages (which some might find easier to use than writing multiple full-fledged extensions themselves). Tampermonkey also exists as a mobile browser for Android, though its usability is debatable:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.biniok.tampermonkey&hl=en&gl=US

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tampermonkey.dolphin

You basically just type in or paste the JS you want to run, and it'll run automatically when you visit a page matching the URL. If you want to go this route, you'll probably find Android Debug Bridge extremely helpful in working out the kinks.

Comment: Is there an equivalent on iOS?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/go954c/using_tampermonkey_scripts_with_shortcuts_on_ios/

Comment: Cool, that's an interesting approach, I've never tried it since I don't have an Apple phone. I haven't found any other options, except for desktop of course https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tampermonkey/id1482490089?mt=12